# Banshee starts a song in a random section

Tags: 11.10, banshee, playback

I'm having a bit of an annoying problem with Banshee. I have a library that's not so big, only 300-400 songs. However, I'm the problem arises when I play songs. When I double click to play a song, it plays normally, as expected. But during a playlist or my whole library, or even a playlist with a single song being played, something funny happens: It starts the next track f.ex. in the middle, but not at the beginning. Rarely at the beginning.
This is quite annoying, and I don't really have an idea what may cause it. It used to work completely fine before, and I find it hard to believe that it may be a matter of a corrupted database in Banshee.

Has anyone else had this problem, and if so, is there any solution to this?

I'm sorry if this is the wrong place to ask, but I believe it'd be appropriate since I do run Ubuntu (11.10) and Banshee is the default player.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problem solved:

The problem was caused by the gapless playback option.
Disabling it made the problem disappear with instant effect. 
There seems to have been a good amount of problems with this feature throughout history when I searched it up. 
The reason why it happens is hard to understand off the bat, but it's most probably a bug.

Comment: It'd be nice if you also accepted your own answer so others can see that it's solved.

Answer (score 0):

### Possible cause:

As hard as it might be to believe, it is most likely a corrupt database.

### Possible solution:

You can backup your database, then rescan your library, and the problem should be gone. If it is not gone, then you need to report a bug (because it would be something wrong in the code and not the database.

### To backup the database:

- Navigate to `/home/yourusername/.config/banshee-1`
- Rename `banshee.db` to something else (such as `bansheebk.db`)

### To rescan the library:

- Open Banshee
- Go to: Tools>Rescan Music Library

Let it complete, then try playing music again and the problem *should* be gone.

Comment: It didn't solve the problem... What I just saw was this: The slider actually moves, all by itself, through the seekbar to some random point. I don't have any idea what that's about. It's a clean, newly made database, too. Would this qualify as a bug, or should I make further research before filing it?